# Combination of Android service, Cordova background plugin and Skype O365 sdk does not working after few hours while running in background?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, skype-for-business

I am working on ionic platform and making one Android and iOS application.

**Application requirement:**
Skype for business O365 login will be there for user and then minimizing the application it will change the status of user like busy, available and note as well on regular interval.

**What I have done:**
I have used [Cordova background mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) and Skype [websdk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/skypewebsdk?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).It's logging in fine and setting the status fine while using in foreground.

**Problem I am facing:**
If I put application in background mode then the status is setting for few minutes but after that somehow it's not setting the status.

So, I am thinking that might be some scenarios:

1. Might the Android or iOS stopping the background service.
2. Might the [cordova background plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) not working properly.
3. Might the [Skype websdk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/skypewebsdk?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) stops after some time while running in background

Getting this error after the 404 not found code.
https://webpooldb41e02.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/1145363530/me/reportMyActivity

I am researching for the above aspects as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Its not about Background plugin. I found that Skype SDK somehow stops working if it stays in same network for more then around 4800 seconds.

What I did is I signed out and signed Back In user with SetInterval. So token will refreshed and It worked for me. You can use signet and signIn with setInterval of 4000 second or so.